# Is the standard complex multiplication the only one that makes $\Bbb R^2$ a field?

Tags: complex-multiplication

If $(a_1,a_2)*(b_1,b_2)=(a_1b_1-a_2b_2,a_1b_2+a_2b_1)$ then $\Bbb R^2$ is a field with pointwise addition and $\ast$

Is there another multiplication $\ast$' that has this property?

Comment: If $K/\Bbb R$ is a 2d extension, then $K=\Bbb R[u]$ for some $u$ with quadratic minimal polynomial $m$. Then it is isomorphic to $\Bbb R[T]/m(T)$, which is also isomorphic to $\Bbb R[v]$ where $v$ is a complex root of $m$, which is just $\Bbb C$. Anyway, this is **not** what the tag (complex-multiplication) is about.

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it.  Cheers!

Comment: @anon The question is actually more subtle than that. Why is $\mathbb R^2$ an extension of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I was presuming $\Bbb R$-bilinearity of the $\ast$-operation (in which case the scalar multiples of $1$ form a copy of $\Bbb R$), but if it's simply additive then I suppose the answer is different, since $\Bbb R^2$ just a $\frak c$-dim vector space over $\Bbb Q$ (so one could cook up any field of characteristic $0$ and cardinality $\frak c$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes if you add few extra natural conditions", but no otherwise.

Here is an example. Pick the field $K= \mathbb R(X)$ of rational functions on $\mathbb R$.

Then $(\mathbb R^2,+)$ and $(\mathbb R(X), +)$ have the same dimension as $\mathbb Q$ vector spaces, therefore they are isomorphic as vector spaces.

In particular, they are isomorphic as abelian groups.

Let $f :  (\mathbb R^2,+) \to (\mathbb R(X), +)$ be any isomorphism.

Define
$$a\star b := f^{-1} (f(a) \cdot f(b))$$

This induces a field structure on $(\mathbb R^2,+)$ and as a field $(\mathbb R^2, + \star)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R(X), +, \cdot)$ which makes it very different than $\mathbb C$.

The same construction works for any extension of $\mathbb R$ of finite transcendence degree.

**But** if you want your $\star$ to be "compatible" with real multiplication, in the sense that, as a field $(\mathbb R^2, + , \star)$ contains a copy of $\mathbb R$ **and** has a finite basis, then the only possibility is, up to isomorphism, complex conjugations.

Comment: While they are all isomorphic to the complexes, it's probably worth explicitly stating that there *are* other possibilities.